# Angular - Form Validation Custom Directive, how to pass result to another element for the error display?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So basically I'm building myself a new directive for form validation and I got it all working perfectly except for 1 thing which I believe is not properly coded. So as you know form validation with a directive is to validate an `<input ngx-validation="alpha">` how do I pass the error text, which occurs inside my directive to the other element (a Bootstrap `<span class="text-danger">{{ validation_errors["input1"] }}</span>` that is right below my input? As for the moment, I created a scope variable which exist inside my controller and it does work...until the user forgets to create that actual variable... So how am I suppose to share the information for 1 element to another? Which by the way, my variable is an array holding all input error messages... Here is my code at the moment:

```
<!-- html form -->
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="input1" ng-model="form1.input1" ngx-validation="alpha|min_len:3|required" />
<span class="validation text-danger">{{ validation_errors["input1"] }}</span>
```

JS Code

```
// my Controller 
myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {
  $scope.form1 = {};
  $scope.validation_errors = [];  // the scope variable
}]);

// creation of my directive
angular.module('ghiscoding.validation', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
  .directive('ngxValidation', function($translate){
    return{
      require: "ngModel",
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        // get the ngx-validation attribute  
        var validationAttr = attrs.ngxValidation;

        // rest of the validation code...
        // ...

        if(!isFieldValid && ctrl.$dirty) {
            scope.validation_errors[ctrl.$name] = message;
        }else {
            scope.validation_errors[ctrl.$name] = "";
        }

        return value;
        };

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validator);
      }
    };
  });
```

If you look at my code, the scope variable in question which I use is called `$scope.validation_errors = [];` which is created in the Controller, without creating it, it will of course fail. You can also see my github, I made it available and also wish that lot of people could use my Angular-Validation directive because it's just so easy the way I've done it :)   See my [Github Angular-Validation](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation)

**EDIT**
Just to make it clear, the validation part of my directive is working fine. My real problem is simply, how do I pass the error message from the directive (which the directive is connected to the `<input>`) and pass that error message (a simple string) to the `<span>` they are 2 different elements, how can I talk to another element within a directive, how can I bind? At the moment I'm using a global variable, which needs to exist in the controller, this isn't good... I am very new to Angular and I'm struggling with directives, so please provide code. Thanks a lot for help.

**ANSWER**
So to have a full Angular Directive, the last piece of code for the solution was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652345/from-inside-a-custom-directive-how-to-change-text-of-another-span-element/21652496?noredirect=1#21652496)... Since the `<span>` for displaying my error message is always after my input, I can simply update the next element text with native Angular jqLite...that's it, as simple as that... Here is my new HTML code

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" name="input1" validation="alpha|min_len:3|required" />
<span class="validation text-danger"></span>
```

```
// Previous piece of code to replace
if(!isFieldValid && ctrl.$dirty) {
    scope.validation_errors[ctrl.$name] = message;
}

// REPLACED by this
if(!isFieldValid && ctrl.$dirty) {
    elm.next().text(message);
}
```

Comment: The other option I found is to use JS or jQuery within my directive. So I add another attribute on my input let say `<input validation-error-id="errorInput1".../>` and give that id to my error `<span id="errorInput1">` and from within my directive use an innerHTML to update the error message...but is ok to do in Angular, maybe not is it?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the same thing as all the other built-in form validation directives do: use the ngModelController's $setValidity method, using your own key. Your span will then be able to check if an error exists for your validation key using

```
theFormName.theInputName.$error.yourValidationKey
```

And the validity of the field, as well as the validity of the enclosing form, will automatically be handled by angular.

See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController.

Comment: eee what? Sorry, I'm new to Angular and I don't seem to get your saying. Would it be possible to show me what I have to change in my code. And please note that I want to leave my directive as reusable, so the `theFormName.` doesn't seem good for re-usability

Comment: BTW I don't know if you saw but I have multiple validation filters  which I pass under 1 directive `ngx-validation="alpha|min_len:3|required"`, you can see 3 are passed in my example... I want to stick with 1 call for all validation of that same input, it's a completely different concept as all other ones I found, but it's so much more easy this way!

Comment: Instead of doing `scope.validation_errors[ctrl.$name] = message`, you should do `ctrl.$setValidity('ngxValidation', false)`. The key (ngxValidation) is up to you. That will make the field invalid, which will cause angular to add css classes to the field to indicate it, and will also cause the enclosing form to become invalid. The documentation I linked to explains it pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for your help JB but unfortunately it seems that you misunderstood my question. The validation part of my directive is working fine, the problem I have is to simply pass the error message from inside my directive to the `<span>` dedicated for the error display. Right now I'm using a global scope variable, this isn't good.

Comment: You shouldn't pass error messages. The directive should only set the field valid or invalid according to a rule (or several ones), and have the span display the appropriate error message depending on which error key is present on the field. Just like on the examples I linked to.