# From inside a custom directive how to change text of another span element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an `<input>` which holds my custom directive as an attribute and inside that attribute I give the ID of destination that will receive the text. At the moment I am doing the text change with jQuery but I would rather use the full Angular way...So it's kinda of a binding but from within a directive. To make it simple, I made a simple draft of my code:

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" name="input1" my-directive="message1" />
<span id="message1"></span>
```

JS Code

```
// Angular - custom Directive
directive('myDirective', function($log) {
    return{
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            var receiverId = attrs.myDirective;
            var whateverText = 'blabla';

            $('#'+receiverId).text(whateverText);
        }
    };
});
```

Using the ID on my `<span>` element is probably not the best solution, but that is how I got it working with jQuery. It's probably better to remove the ID, but then how could I update the text in my span after all? And let's not forget that it's a Form and we can have multiple input and span elements. Also note that I do not want to use the controller to pass the text, it has to stay within the directive as I want to re-use it.

Please don't tell me that I shouldn't do it this way, I want to stick with this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `<span>` will always be the next sibling as per your example, just use `elm.next()` as it is supported in Angular's native [jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element), no need to wrap with jQuery, e.g.

```
directive('myDirective', function($log) {
    return{
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            var receiverId = attrs.myDirective;
            var whateverText = 'blabla';

            elm.next().text(whateverText);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Excellent!!! I knew it was simple...thanks for jqLite link. This was the last piece of code I needed for my awesome Angular-Validation...please take a look, I'm sure you'll want to use it after :)   https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation